# Algorithm for the following homework

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

You require an algorithm to read in one customer's account balance at the begining of the month, a total of all withdrawals for the month, and a total of all deposits made during the month. A federal tax charge of 1% is applied to all transactions made during the month. The program is to calculate the account balance at end of the month by (1) subtracting the total withdrawals from the account balance at the beginning of the month, (2) adding the total deposits to new balance, (3) calculating the federal tax (1% of total transactions - that is, total withdrawals+total deposits), and (4) subtracting this federal tax from the new balance. After these calculations, print the final end-of-month balance.

Comment: Looks like a homework question to mee

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. If it is that you don't understand the assignment, you have to be specific about what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: In the title you ask for an algorithm, but your question already contains the algorithm, so just as Guffa I ask: what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This will be a straightforward translation into pseudocode. As this is a homework assignment¸ you'll have to do the legwork yourself. Just evaluate each step in turn:

```
input: accountBalanceStart, totalDeposits, totalWithdrawals
output: accountBalanceEnd
```

Let's take the first step:

```
accountBalanceEnd <-- accountBalanceStart - totalWithdrawals
```

Now the second:

```
accountBalanceEnd <-- accountBalanceEnd + totalDeposits
```

Next, compute the tax and subtract it:

```
accountBalanceEnd <-- accountBalanceEnd - (totalWithdrawals + totalDeposits) * 0.01
```

Finally, show the result:

```
print accountBalanceEnd
```

Comment: Would'nt it be a cleaner solution to store in a table with (amount, account_id, date) and not deposits and withdrawals separately,so one could just do a SUM(amount)?

Comment: That's not how the input to the problem was defined. It's pretty clear that you get a single customer's account balance, their total withdrawals, and their total deposits. Then you're asked to (given this information) compute the final balance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be the homework problem on www.palinfonet.com/hw_java2008.pdf due April 17th 2008, question #3.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other posters, that this is neither a question nor is this a place where people are going to do your homework. But just in case you really absolutely have no clue I give a more concrete example.

What you most likely will need to read:

[PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL)

[SQL Quickref](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp)

I would probably try something like this. I intendedly haven't tested or commented it and the syntax might also be wrong for mssql.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_Balance(account_id long, account_balance float, date datetime) RETURNS float AS
    DECLARE
    transactions_sum float;
    fed_tax float;
    new_account_balance float;              
BEGIN
    transactions_sum = SELECT SUM(amount) from transactions 
        WHERE transactions.account_id = account_id 
        AND month(transactions.date) = month(date) 
        AND year(transactions.date) = year(date);

    fed_tax = transactions_sum * 0,01;
    transactions_sum = transactions_sum - fed_tax;
    new_account_balance = transactions_sum + account_balance;

    RETURN new_account_balance;
END;
```

Comment: I think there's a logic error on your fed_tax line. If there were 100 transactions in a month, you would be charging federal tax equal to the full sum! The *number* of transactions isn't relevant, only the total size.

Comment: I was wondering about that too.
Seems I misunderstood "A federal tax charge of 1% is applied to all transactions made during the month". Thought this was another "strange tax" ;) Edited.